# Why typescript non-null does not work when used with casting?

Tags: typescript

I have a code similar to the one below (with `--strictNullChecks`):

```typescript
interface Apple {
    id: string;
}

const applesWithoutError = [{}] as Apple[]; // No error
const applesWithError: Apple[] = [{}]; // Error: Property 'id' is missing in type '{}'type 'Apple[]'
```

Why isn't `applesWithoutError` detected as a compilation error?

Answer (score 5):

This happens because a type assertion (a.k.a casting) overrides what the compiler knows about the types. So if you tell the compiler `applesWithoutError` is `Apple[]` it will ignore what it knows to be true in favour of what you tell it to be true.

Comment: Here is a great discussion on TypeScript's type assertions: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html